# Usb condense mic is not working on 22.04

Tags: usb, 22.04, configuration, hardware, microphone

I have condenser microphone kit newly brought from amazone. This device is working with my mobile and windows PC but nirdosh working in ubantu.

1. my laptop internal mic is working
2. Am able to record audio and video with screen recorder.
   3.when I pug in my new usb microphone it's detecting but not working.